# remove string that contain both letters and numbers in python

Tags: python, preprocessor, isalpha

I have a String

```
c=("Snap-on Power M1302A5 Imperial,IMPRL 0.062IN")
```

and I need to convert above string to

```
c=("Snap-on Power Imperial,IMPRL")
```

i.e i need to remove string that has both letters and numbers,

How can I do this in python?

I tried with

```
c=c.apply(word_tokenize)
c = c.apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if item.isalpha()])
```

but got output

```
c=("Snap-on Power MA Imperial,IMPRL IN")
```

Comment: you haven't defined `apply`

Comment: How long are the strings? looks like you could split it and then remove any entries that contain a letter and number, not sure how efficient it would be.

Comment: it seems like you want to remove such tokens (substrings) in which case you must define your tokenisation rules

Comment: Should it also remove numbers like `1976` or leave them in the string?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure exactly what you want here, but it seems you want to remove words that have a digit in them. In that case, you can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#any) here:

```
>>> c = "Snap-on Power M1302A5 Imperial,IMPRL 0.062IN"
>>> ' '.join(w for w in c.split() if not any(x.isdigit() for x in w))
Snap-on Power Imperial,IMPRL
```

Answer (score 3):

Also adding a `regex` based solution:

```
c = "Snap-on Power M1302A5 Imperial,IMPRL 0.062IN"
only_a = []
for word in c.split():
    #print(word)
    if not re.search('\d',word):
        #print(word)
        only_a.append(word)
' '.join(only_a)
```

Output: `'Snap-on Power Imperial,IMPRL'`

Answer (score 1):

To select words without digit

```
c = ' '.join([item for item in c.split() if not any(filter(str.isdigit, item))])
# ['Snap-on', 'Power', 'Imperial,IMPRL']
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer does the same thing as other answers

Step 1: Split the string into different words

Step 2: Check if each word contains numbers, if it does skip the word

Step 3: Generate a string from the words without numbers

```
line = "Snap-on Power M1302A5 Imperial,IMPRL 0.062IN"

split_line = line.split(" ")

final_split_string = []

for word in split_line:
    skip_word = False
    for letter in word:
        if letter.isdigit():
            #check if the current word contains a number
            skip_word = True

    if not skip_word:
        #skip a word if it contains number
        final_split_string.append(word)

final_string = " ".join(final_split_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
c="Snap-on Power M1302A5 Imperial,IMPRL 0.062IN"
import re
pattern=r'\d'

final=[]
for i in c.split():
    if isinstance(i.split(','),list):
        for m in i.split(','):
            if re.search(pattern,m):
                pass
            else:
                final.append(m)

print(" ".join(final))
```

output:

```
Snap-on Power Imperial IMPRL
```